# How to speed up NFS random access

Tags: linux, nfs

I have had this problem ever since I've been using NFS (10+ years), but it's become more apparent with the recent advent of SSDs.

I have a LAN setup with two directly connected servers with each two 1GBit/s bonded Ethernet cards. NFS server and client are Debian 8. I export a directory from the server which is on a SSD.

I have no problem with throughput, I read files with more than 150MB/s, `atop` shows peak transfer of 1.6Gbps/s, which is ok. Writing is around 125MB/s with sync, 160MB/s with async.

However, random access+write times seem to be a problem. My actual benchmark is building a Java application. The build process is parallelized, up to 6 threads and CPU performance is not a problem. On a local SSD, the build process takes about 90 seconds.

When I build the same application on an NFS mount, performance is abysmal. Build takes about 4 minutes on NFSv3 (async) and about 7 minutes on NFSv4 (async). I haven't had the partience for testing with sync, it's even slower.

Running a NFS Test suite showed that with NFSv4, write delegation seems to fail. I have not found any hints on how to enable it.

I don't expect any network file system to perform as well as a local one, but a factor of 3 or 4 really makes this really unusable.

The build process read about 500MB and writes about 1GB.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/docs/nfs4perf/nfs4perf-microscope.pdf

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I did see this, but haven't fully read it. It does provide some hints as to where performance issues may occur, but are there any concrete methods of improving it?

Comment: @StefanSeidel Did you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @gxx no, the more research I do, the more I come to the conclusion that network file systems will always be at least one magnitude slower than local file systems, due to the overhead of the network protocol. With the abundance of fast storage nowadays, even fewer people seem to care, so there's not much hope of improvement.